# How to show the current progressBar value of process within a loop in flex-as3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I dont know how to show the current progress in progressBar component when the process is a loop that requires a lot of seconds to do the job. 
Inside the loop, i setProgress and update the progressBar label in every cicle, but it is not shown up to the job is done. I dont need this, because i want to see the advance of process.
thank you.

Comment: So nothing is being updated until the whole task is finished? Is it actually calling the 'setProgress' function in your loop? Can you trace it to see if the regular updates are happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, just instead for or while you need to use Timers.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var loopNum : uint = 17598; // loop length ( forrmer for or while limit )
var tick : uint = 0;

var timer:Timer = new Timer ( 10, loopNum );
timer.addEventListener ( TimerEvent.TIMER, handleLoopTick );
timer.start ();

function handleLoopTick ( e : TimerEvent )
{
    trace ( this, ( tick / loopNum ) * 100 ); // outputs percentage for example

    tick++; // increasing the tick
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an ordinary loop like `for` or `while` the answer is: it is impossible. Loops in Flash are synchronous but all the animations (including programming) are frame based asynchronous. So the only way is to distribute your loop across multiply frames.