# AS3.0 Two For-loops with a delay

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, delay

I've got the following code and i would like to add an delay of 200 ms after each trace statement

```
for (var x_pos:uint = 0; x_pos <= 12; x_pos++){ 
    for (var y_pos:uint = 0; y_pos <=12; y_pos++){
        trace("hello world " +"("x_pos+","+y_pos+")");
        //CODE FOR DELAY OF 200ms    
    }
}
```

The real situation is a bit more complex but kind of the same:

```
//For each Row 
for (var x_pos:uint = 0; x_pos <= tile_amount-1; x_pos++){
    //For each column 
    for (var y_pos:uint = 0; y_pos <= tile_amount-1; y_pos++){
        //New tile;
        var newtile:Tile = new Tile;

        //Set position
        newtile.x = ((40*y_pos)-(40*x_pos));
        newtile.y = ((20*y_pos)+(20*x_pos));

        //Add to stage 
        addChild(newtile);
    }
}
```

Anyone any suggestions ?

Comment: What sense would this make? For debugging use as debugger not delayed traces.

Comment: Well the real situation is a little different but i wanted to make the question as simple as possible. 

I actually want to add different tiles of a game with a delay to the stage and the for loops are needed to set the height/width. I'll adjust the question in a sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop the execution of code in the middle of a statement like that, your best bet is to use a timer:

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Foo
    {

        private var x_pos:uint = 0;
        private var y_pos:uint = 0;
        private var timer:Timer;

        public function Foo()
        {
            timer = new Timer(200, 0);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTick);
            timer.start();
        }


        public function handleTick(e:TimerEvent):void {

            trace("hello world " +"("x_pos+","+y_pos+")");
            y_pos++;
            if(y_pos > 12){
                x_pos++;
                y_pos = 0;
            }

            if(x_pos > 12) timer.stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. Though it is not perfect because some other classes are depending on the loading of this class. To they cannot execute while this loop is still running.

Comment: You also don't stop the timer from working. Jesus, this is a pretty dirty way to gain rep.

Comment: I did not "steal" your answer, mine is posted a mere minute after yours, you were a bit quicker than I was with the same answer. The timer is stopped on the last line in the handleTick function.

Answer (score 4):

```
private var x_pos:uint;
private var y_pos:uint;
private var timer:Timer;

public function startLoop():void
{
    x_pos = 0;
    y_pos = 0;

    timer = new Timer(200);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
    timer.start();
}

private function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace("hello world " +"("x_pos+","+y_pos+")");

    if (++y_pos <= 12)
        return;

    y_pos = 0;
    if (++x_pos <= 12)
        return;

    timer.stop();
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
    timer = null;
}
```

Comment: can you really use `continue` in that fashion?

Comment: then i get: `Line 34: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property TIMER through a reference with static type Class.`

Comment: @grapefrukt - I meant to write "return" rather than "continue", you must have commented after I offered the solution, before I edited.

Comment: @Tieme, thanks. I also meant to put TimerEvent rather than Event. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

You can not delay the loops in as3.

For this purpose you need to use timers. Some help for your solution you can find here: [How to show the current progressBar value of process within a loop in flex-as3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792210/how-to-show-the-current-progressbar-value-of-process-within-a-loop-in-flex-as3/5793156#5793156)

At the end you just need to modify the function logic.

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript does not have a blocking timeout system -- you need to do a recursive function of your own. This following perfect, but it is a start.

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

// call the final function.
delayedRecursion(12,12,200, 
   function(curX:Number, curY:Number):void
   {
      trace("hello world " +"("+curX+","+curY+")");
   });

//This is really a wrapper around delayedRecursionHelper
function delayedRecursion(maxX:Number, maxY:Number, 
                          delay:Number, callback:Function):void
{
     delayedRecursionHelper(0,-1,maxX,maxY,delay,callback);
}

// each time you call this, it creates a function which holds the variables
// passed in, but incremented by 1.
function delayedRecursionHelper( 
                                 curX:Number, cury:Number, 
                                 maxX:Number, maxY:Number, 
                                 delay:Number, called:Function ):Function
{
    return function():void
    {
        called(curX, curY);
        // Exit condition: nothing to do here!
        if( curX == maxX && curY == maxY ) return; 
        if( curY == maxY )
        {
            curY = -1;
            curX++;
        }
        curY++;
        setTimeout(delayedRecursionHelper(curX, curY, maxX, maxY, delay), delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, the TimerEvent answers are better form, but this is more technically neat and it does not have any truly stateful variables!

Comment: This code makes my head spin, but it's an interesting solution!