# AS3 Error #1502

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, compiler-errors

AS3
Error: Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.

Is there a way to temporarily suppress this on a specific block of code?

I am creating a HUGE dynamic 3d array of objects, 1000x1000x1000 and need the build to actually finish the initializing.

Comment: To sum up the answers. No. You can increase the timeout for the entire program. Or you can split up the array creation into parts to keep things running smoothly (Which seems the best bet for a situation that may require a ridiculously large array(s)) Our good old actionscript guru Senocular has a bit on how to do that. http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/asyncoperations/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would be to try and refactor your code. Perhaps you can make use of this tutorial which deals with the exact problem you are having.

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/asyncoperations/

Comment: Oh, wow. That is a fantastic theory. I love that. Imma have to use it. Interesting stuff!

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the timeout is one option, however I would also suggest considering an approach that would build your arrays over multiple frames, that is splitting the work up into separate jobs. As long as you give control back to the Flash Player every once in a while, you will not get this exception.

I'm not certain of the specifics of your problem, however you will need to find a way to parallelize or just simply segment your calculations. If your algorithm centers around one major loop, then consider creating a function that takes all of the arguments necessary to record the context of a single iteration. Then, create a simple control loop that will call this function and determine when to wait until the next frame and when not to. Leveraging AS3 closures can also help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the script execution time limit in the "Publish Settings" (Flash). If you're using Flex, maybe [this one](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html) can be useful: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html (check default-script-limits, max-recursion-depth, max-execution-time). Oh! It seems there's apparently no way to make it behave in a different way on a specific piece of code (it is a global setting).

Answer (score 0):

I do not approve the increse timeout option. Because for all this time your appllication is just hangs the whole Flash player. And normaly user thinks it is down, and forses it to quit.

check this one out: [How to show the current progressBar value of process within a loop in flex-as3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792210/how-to-show-the-current-progressbar-value-of-process-within-a-loop-in-flex-as3/5793156#5793156)

And then you can even show the progress which would be really more confident for you and for user.